# How to talk to a BLE device using Android phone?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an app to communicate with a BLE device (Sensor puck from Silicon labs) and get whatever it is broadcasting.

I have NO experience in developing any sort of Bluetooth application using Android.

1. Do I need to manually pair it to the BLE device? I downloaded Sensor puck app from Play store, it automatically started to read from the device. I don't understand how since I didn't pair it.
2. Do I need specific API to communicate with the device? Is it like, I connect to the device and unpack the data which the device is broadcasting?

Any other information related to BLE application development would help.

Thank you.

PS: I can't use the app from the play store as I need the data from the device for some other processing.

Answer (score 1):

I have a little experience with developing BLE apps.

> Do I need to manually pair it to the BLE device?

I haven't encountered use case where I needed to pair mobile device with BLE device. Basically, you can communicate with BLE devices without pairing with them. BLE devices constantly emit signals and you can read these signals. Usually, from the emitted signals, you can read name of the device (or producer name), MAC address, RSSI signal from which you can compute distance from your mobile device to BLE device. Some BLE devices emit other information like temperature read from their sensors, etc. You can read information from more than one BLE device during the single scan.

> Do I need specific API to communicate with the device?

Google provides API, which you can use to communicate with BLE devices. You can read more about it at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html. You can also use some third-party libraries allowing to communicate with BLE devices. Most of them are dedicated to so called Beacons, which are simple, tiny BLE devices.

Exemplary APIs for BLE Beacons:

- [Estimote](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK)
- [Kontakt.io](https://github.com/kontaktio/Android-SDK)
- [AltBeacon](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library)
- [ReactiveBeacons](https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveBeacons) - this is open-source project, which I'm currently developing, so if you have any questions regarding it, you can ask me directly

Other projects:

- [Android Bluetooth Demo](https://github.com/Pixplicity/android-bluetooth-demo) - this is very good and simple project, which can help you to understand how to use BLE API provided in Android SDK

Other information:

To communicate with BLE devices, of course, you need to have Bluetooth enabled on your device, but regardless of this permission, you also need to have Location enabled on your device and added location permission to your app. I guess it's done due to the fact, that you can use BLE devices for creating micro-location services.

I gathered some references concerning BLE for myself. You can check them here: https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveBeacons#references and maybe they will be useful for you as well.

Regards,

Piotr

Answer (score 0):

it might be too late, but it also might be helpful for other users. So Sensor Puck works like a simple beacon and it doesn't require any pairing. You just have to scan all bluetooth devices nerby and verify received ScanRecord object.  You don't have to use any specific libs or API, Anroid sdk contain all necessary api for such case (please see BluetoothAdapter startScan, startLeScan, etc). Also you can find an example how to parse raw data in my demo project https://github.com/alexeyosminin/sensor_puck_demo